# How to add a button in FitNesse Test case?

Tags: java, fitnesse, fitnesse-slim, fixture, selenium-fitnesse-bridge

The scenario is as follow:
**I want to pause the test when it encounters the Button in the Wiki page Test Scenario. It should wait until the user presses the Button and once the button is pressed the test should continue.**

Comment: The whole point of FitNesse is to automate tests so that no user interaction is required.

Comment: Can you elaborate why this is needed? Is the button expected to be in the page/application being tested, or in the test page in the wiki (so part of the test)?

Comment: i need a button on Fitnesse page to allow users to make changes on the page and save it on the.. The best mechanism i thought would be to add Commit button on header and call PHP -> SH script .. but i am getting CORS error again and again.,.. Is there any way we can do it..

Answer (score 1):

As the automated tests are designed to run in a full set without any monitoring or midway user interaction, this is not a standard feature. Feel free to edit the source where needed and recompile.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged this question with Selenium-fitnesse-bridge, my assumption is that you are testing the browser user interface of an application via Selenium webDriver, but instead of driving the tests from xUnit you are driving from fitnesse.

First, this isn't really the sweet spot of fitnesse - it's main purpose is to test business logic by interacting with System Under Test as opposed to running end-end tests by driving a browser - however, that soap box aside, you are creating fixtures for fitnesse to interact with - and those fixtures currently contain webdriver code.  So you can put the pause inside your fixture class.  I'd need to see your test table and whether you are using Slim or not to get an idea of where the logical place in your fixture code to place the wait would be.

The only problem with that solution is if you want to specify on the fixture page that there should be a wait at a certain point - you don't just want it behind the scenes in the webdriver code.  In that case, you could probably use a ScriptTable style of fixture (http://www.fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.WritingAcceptanceTests.SliM.ScriptTable)  and have a command in the script that maps to a method that waits for the specified amount of time or for a specified element to be visible.